# Replace Html tags from string in java

Tags: java, html, regex

My requirement is to replace the html tags in the string.

1. I have tried using Jsoup and other parsers .
2. I tried with regular expressions .

But the problem is they are removing content which is not html also.

Example:

```
<p>hi Hello</p>Second Hi Hello <span id=\"true\">If B<A then A>B &amp; this is true</span> After body in message body normal text.
```

Expected output:

```
hi Hello Second Hi Hello If B<A then A>B  this is true After body in message body normal text
```

Actual output:

```
hi Hello Second Hi Hello If BB  this is true After body in message body normal text
```

Could someone let me know the possible approaches?

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  I have Check almost all articles related. I have used Jsoup but it removed non html content between <> tags.

Comment: > and < must be encoded to &gt; and &lt; or they are html tag parts.

Comment: they are not html tag parts. But how to encode only less than,greater than apart from html tags.

Comment: That's not possible, it's a matter of interpretation. You could perhaps use the fact that there never are spaces in html tags